# How to create a SQL VIEW when using Eloquent outside of Laravel

Tags: php, sql, eloquent

When using Eloquent outside of Laravel and using the **Capsule\Manager** class, I can't see how to create a SQL view, only a SQL table.  When using Eloquent with Laravel, you can do something like:

```
DB::statement( "CREATE VIEW foo AS SELECT id, name FROM . . .
```

But the **Capsule\Manager** class doesn't have a statement() method or any way to execute raw SQL (like the statement() method does) that I can see.

The **Capsule\Manager** class seems to let you do everything else you can normally do with Eloquent, surely there's a way to create a view?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to execute raw SQL you can use Manager::connection() to get the connection object which has `statement` and `raw` methods. Try this:

```
$db = \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager::connection();
$db->statement($db->raw('CREATE VIEW `foo` AS SELECT * FROM `bar`'));
```